# codeigniter: Message: Module 'mysqli' already loaded

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

I'm setting up a new project in codeigniter and after uploading all files to the live server, I got this error upon loading the website:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Core Warning

Message: Module 'mysqli' already loaded

Filename: Unknown

Line Number: 0

Backtrace:
```

It's given line number 0 and I don't where I made the mistake. I'm not getting this error in localhost. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: How you resolve?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to load the php module the second time. It's probably already set to load in `php.ini` file, and you try to load again dynamically somewhere inside your project. 
You could either comment that line inside `php.ini` and restart Apache, or find and delete the line that could be something like

```
dl('php_mysqli.dll'); // on Windows
```

or

```
dl('mysqli.so'); // on Linux
```

,somewhere inside a .php file.

Better yet, test before attempting to load:

```
if (!extension_loaded('mysqli')) {
    dl('php_mysqli.dll');
}
```