# Severity: Core Warning Message: Module 'mysqli' already loaded

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

I was developing a website via localhost, everything was working well, but I just uploaded the website online, everything else seems to work well except this sticky message below my footer :
`

```
 A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Core Warning

Message: Module 'mysqli' already loaded

Filename: Unknown

Line Number: 0

Backtrace:
```

`

Its showing line number 0, I have no idea what this means. If this can be fixed, How? and if so, is the problem from my side or my hosting providers?

Comment: Have you tried loading database repeatedly?

Comment: Im not even loading database, from autoload. Coz Im not using it anywhere, as of now

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40759519/codeigniter-message-module-mysqli-already-loaded check this

Comment: @kishor10d where is that file  `dl('php_mysqli.dll'); ` ....Im using windows, but I think hosting provider is using Linux server

Comment: @Lexie Just check that **Only** the first letter of classes and filenames is uppercase. That goes for controllers, models, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1) Controller class name should start with capital.

2) Filename name should start with capital.

Because Linux is case sensitive.

Comment: controllers are all starting with Caps

Comment: which file exactly?

Comment: all file name same as a controller name